# How to identify leaks objects using Leaks in XCode 4?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, xcode4

Can any one guide me that how to use and identify the variables that are leaking the memory?

I took the snap as following, but yet no idea to understand it

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the right utility area (click third button next to the status info in the top bar).
when you then klick on a leaked block (and on the arrow next to the address), you can see the code blocks responsible for the steps